# Option payoff diagrams in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I generate an option payoff diagram such as this in LaTeX with `PGFPlots` or `TikZ`?

[image]

Comment: Do you have the equations for the curves?

Comment: [`pgfplots` manual section 3.3](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) is the first place showing multiple plots on a single axis. Can you start from there and provide a MWE with what fails?

Comment: The equations are discontinuous. Might be better to specify start and end coordinates for the lines etc.

Comment: From your previous questions, it seems like you already know how to use PGFPlots. Could you maybe make this question more specific? For example "How do I plot discontinuous functions using PGFPlots?", if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Which in turn means "How do I compute discontinuous functions using pgfmath?"  Actually, piecewise continuous.

Answer (score 4):

Here is something to get you started. The piecewise-continuous function is defined using the facilities of TikZ, while the plotting and styling is left to `pgfplots`.

Since we do not know which functions are to be plotted, I simply guessed at a close piecewise-linear function and a quadratic function roughly following the provided screenshot. The correct functions are easily substituted into the `declare function` code and the second `\addplot` command, respectively.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  declare function={
    mypl(\x)= -1.25 + (\x>25) * (0.9*(\x-25));
  }
]
\begin{axis}[
  domain=20:30,
  axis lines=middle,
  legend style={
    draw=none,
    legend columns=-1,
    at={(0.5,1)},
    anchor=south,
    outer sep=1em,
    node font=\small,
  },
]
  \addplot[blue,thick] {mypl(x)};
  \addlegendentry{P\&L at Expiration}
  \addplot[pink] {0.05*(x-20)^2-1.25};
  \addlegendentry{P\&L + 60\,Days};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any chance you could use the Black-Scholes option pricing formula instead of a quadratic for the red line?

Comment: @Mico sure, if I had a clue what that was... :-D The OP was asked what functions were needed and never responded.

Comment: Yeah, I had noticed as well that the OP failed to mention which function underlies the red (or pink) line. A starting point might be [this Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black%E2%80%93Scholes_model). The key parameter is `\sigma`, the expected volatility of the asset that for which the call option represents a right-to-buy (though not an obligation-to-buy). The higher `\sigma`, the further the pink line will be above the blue line. For now, it may be enough if you point out that the function you've drawn is a quadratic, rather than the actual Black-Scholes function.